# Why is DataTables not filling record while downloading Excel, pdf

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

I want to download excel pdf and search Item in my HTML Table. For that I was refereeing [this article](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html).

Here I have added all reference to my HTML

**References**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.0/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

But it is not working as expected expect search text box and while downloading Excel or PDF it's not reflecting table record it's only showing `<title>Mobile User Login</title>` text why so?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#displaytable').hide();
    $('#test').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    });
```

**Table**

```html
<table id="test" class="width100p borderTable table_new">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th></th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
</table>
```

**AJAX Method**

```
var AllDataGrid = [];
function load_DataForGrid() {
    //debugger;
    var params = {
        UserName: $('#txtUserName').val(), UserID: $('#txtUserIDEdit').val(),
        Status: $('input[name="Status"]:checked').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        url: "MobileUser_Login.aspx/Get_Data",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            FunctionalDataForGrid(result.d)
            OnSuccessFunctionalGridCall();
        },
        error: function (err) { // Added this event to capture the failed requests.
            console.log(err);
        }
    });

    function FunctionalDataForGrid(pdata) {
        AllDataGrid = pdata;
    }
    function OnSuccessFunctionalGridCall(data, status) {
        //d = data.GetDraftedSDDResult.ResultObject;
        d = AllDataGrid;
        var tbl = "<table id='lineItemTable' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3' width='100%'>";
        if ($('#test').length != 0)  // remove table if it exists              
        { $('#test').empty(); }

        if (d.length == 0) {
            alert('No Record to display');
        }
        else {

            tbl += "<tr class='tr-Highlighted' style='height:30px;'><td class='align-text-center' >Sr.No</td><td class='align-text-center' style='font-weight:bold !important'>User Login</td><td id='tdUserName' class='align-text-center' style='font-weight:bold !important'>User Name</td><td class='align-text-center' style='font-weight:bold !important'>Status</td><td class='align-text-center' style='font-weight:bold !important'>Action</td></tr>";

            for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                tbl += "<tr><td class='width4p align-text-center'>"
                    + (i + 1) + "</td><td class='width10p'>"
                    + d[i].USER_LOGIN + "</td><td class='width24p'>"
                    + d[i].USER_NAME + "</td><td class='width14p'>"
                    + d[i].Status + "</td><td class='width4p'>" +
                    "<a href='#my_modal' data-toggle='modal' class='open-AddBookDialog' data-book-id='my_id_value'><img src='Images/edit.png' height='20' width='20'></a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href='#my_modal' class='delete-Record'><img src='Images/delete.png' height='18' width='18'></a></td>";
            }
            $("#test").append(tbl);
            $('#hdnReworkStatusData').val(tbl);
            Paggination();
            return;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

**Web Method Returning Data Sample**

[image]

**Rendering Screen Looks like**

[image]

I am binding my table using AJAX call. while clicking Excel or PDF file is downloading but it does not contain table data its just displaying my form title text. I don't understand why it so  `<title> Some Text </title>`

**JSON Data**

[image]

Comment: without showing the ajax script it will be difficult to analyze the issue, can you show some reference data as well as data table ajax code which is being used to pull?

Comment: @MuhammadAsif  Yes for sure i am updating complete AJAX method kindly check my updated code

Comment: @MuhammadAsif Kindly check my updated code I have added `AJAX method` as well as sample data returning from `WebMethod`

Comment: Question: Why you are not binding same buttons in same ajax success call? , the problem is those buttons are being defined on client side, instead they should be defined in same ajax call. Kindly check Server Side Manual in data tables website.

Comment: @MuhammadAsif you mean i need to call `$('#test').DataTable({`  instead of `ready function ` i should call `AJAX` ryt ?

Comment: After Ajax success call , see this example , only for understanding purose:   $("#test").dataTable({      
       "bProcessing": true, 
      "pageLength": 6,   
    "searching": false,
     "order": [[ 1, "DESC" ]],     
                'serverMethod': 'post', 
       dom: 'Bfrtip',  
      "ajax": {
       "url": "url",
       "type": "POST",   
       "dataType": "json",              
       'data': function(ts){         
       
       },
      },

                ],
     buttons: [
               'csv', 'excel', 'pdf','pageLength'
                ]
        });
    });

Comment: @MuhammadAsif can you please suggest me instead of `"url" : "My web method URL"` ryt ? and what about `function(ts)` acording to my code what should be ?

Comment: @MuhammadAsif can you please post as a answer so that i can fix this issues Please

Comment: @MuhammadAsif can you please post as a answer so that i can fix this issues Please i have implemented my code in such a way that after appending my table in `AJAX` method i have written `$("#test").DataTable({ "bProcessing": true, "pageLength": 6, ..... so on `  But i am getting error like  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property  'aDataSort'  of undefined`

Comment: I cannot post an answer as I am not expert in .net language, as it is most important that how you are pushing json data back from .net, but if you can follow the same guidelines posted on datatables server side than you can achieve the desired result.

Comment: You just have to mention after ajax success,
                buttons: [
                    'copyHtml5',
                    'excelHtml5',
                    'csvHtml5',
                    'pdfHtml5'
                ]

Comment: @MuhammadAsif i have done in same manner but not working `function OnSuccessFunctionalGridCall(data, status) { d = AllDataGrid; $('#test').DataTable({....so on  and Button Code ` but no changes i found

Comment: give me full url and I will test and try to fix the issue and will post it back.  full url means the url you are getting data from, like is it hosted live or on local, if live than give me full data url.

Comment: @MuhammadAsif sorry i am using local Sir. is there any another alternate so that we can do please

Comment: one thing, give me json data which you are getting via ajax call

Comment: Ajax Returning `PASSWORD: "123"
Status: "Active"
USER_LOGIN: "1212"
USER_NAME: "nitish"` its returning in the form of array i have also posted in my code Kindly check once Asif

Comment: Dear, kindly take the data from console.log as it is and paste it here, as still the length and other attributes of json data is missing.